# How can I keep discord python bot running without keeping my computer on?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to setup a server that can keep my python discord bot running 24/7 without my computer being on. Issue I've been having is with discord.py not being importable on online servers I've tried. Is there any free way I could do this?

Comment: So a good way to go would be [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/python) (I never used for Python, but they support it), in the [Python docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-app-dependencies) you can see how to install your dependencies. You must do a `requirements.txt ` and install it. I think that should work just fine for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the suggestions online show to be leaning towards repli and heruko (free) being the host, which would suggest as long as you have all the required packages installed and a server of your own (guarantee of 24/7 availability),  and then signing up with discord for the Auth key. In general it's completely possible :)

A little more info over on:
https://www.codementor.io/garethdwyer/building-a-discord-bot-with-python-and-repl-it-miblcwejz

Comment: The tutorial looks great and the only issue I ran into was when downloading discord.py it came up with this error that said that I needed to upgrade my pip

Comment: Try: pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Tried it came up with this error: 
```Repl.it: Installing fresh packages
Usage: pip3 [options]

pip3: error: no such option: --upgrade

You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.```

Comment: Perhaps one of these: python -m pip install --upgrade pip OR pip3 install --upgrade pip3

Comment: First one had same result, second one did better but still failed. I cannot attach the error for the second one as it surpasses the character limit, here is a link to a pastebin with it: [link](https://pastebin.com/jqqVgR7b)

Comment: 2 -- before upgrade :)

Comment: I ran pip3 install 2 --upgrade pip3 and it came with this error code: Repl.it: Installing fresh packages

Usage: pip3 [options]

pip3: error: no such option: --upgrade

You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.


Repl.it: package installation failed!

Comment: I suggest raising a new question on upgrading pip on repli, so as to keep the current question clear of confusion, as you encountered issues with: pip3 install --upgrade pip3